# Count values in Pandas data Frame -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set as such
[image]

For simplicity -Let's say I want to calculate the number of type of each manufacturer of the plane.
[image]

I want the output as such-

```
BOEING-xxx
EMBRAER-xxx
MCDONNELL-XXX
:
:
:
so on
```

How can I do this ? Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dataframe['manufacturer'].value_counts()` to get the result that you want;

However, note that you have `NaNs` in your column; so prior to applying the function above, use:

```
dataframe.dropna(subset=['manufacturer'],inplace=True)
```

Summing it up:

1. `dataframe.dropna(subset=['manufacturer'],inplace=True)`
2. `dataframe['manufacturer'].value_counts()`